# Obtaining Anderson's Bridge Balance Equation

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, kirchhoffs-laws, bridge

I'm trying to learn Anderson's Bridge Balance equation.I dont know how this value is obtained

[image]

Why are they equating the voltage drops across branch one and the sum of the voltage drop across branch 2 and the one with the capacitor?
Please advice

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition of bridge's balance, when the bridge is balanced the voltage \$V_\mathrm{D}\$ across the detector D is zero.

If you write the Kirchhoff's voltage law to the loop comprising branches 1, 2, C and D, you get

$$I_1(r_1+R_1 + \mathrm{j}\omega L_1)+V_\mathrm{D}-rI_C -R_2I_2=0$$

Since \$V_\mathrm{D}=0\$, you obtain equation (15.24).

Note, from the schematic, that the current \$I_C\$ is not only the current crossing the capacitor, but it's also the current which crosses the resistance \$r\$, because at balance the current which crosses the detector is zero.

Comment: But how do you get the sign conventions.. i only know KVL for mesh analysis.. Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYg8B-ElK0s

Comment: @elecman: There are several ways to define sign conventions, all equivalent. I use the following. First, choose an arbitrary direction to traverse the loop: in the example above I chose to traverse the loop in the clockwise direction starting from branch 1.  Then, if the polarity of the branch voltage corresponds to the associated direction with the loop direction take the positive sign, otherwise take the negative: for instance, in the example above, since the current \$I_1\$ agrees with the chosen loop direction, I take the voltage \$I_1(r_1+R_1+\mathrm{j}\omega L_1)\$ with positive sign.

Comment: Instead, \$I_C\$ and \$I_2\$ oppose the chosen loop direction, and I take for them the negative sign. For \$V_\mathrm{D}\$ I chose an arbitrary sign because it doesn't count.

Comment: @elecman However, if you have a specific doubt about how to write KVL, it would be better to ask another question.